# Best Method for Creating Build pipeline

Tags: git, azure-pipelines

I have a branch from which i need to create a build pipeline what will be the best method?

**The one i work now TFVC (i am migrating from TFVC to GIT) :**

- 1) Get latest Commit message
- 2) If it is newer then last build - trigger a build
- 3) Update Version Number on configuration file
- 4) Create a temp Commit message
- 5) Compile / Test / Create Install
- 6) If all succeeded -> Changes Temp commit message to Build Number
- 7) Fail-> Temp Commit Message to Failed Build Reason

**On Git I cannot edit the commit message**

Working with GIT 2.22 on Windows

**Server - is Azure DevOps Server 2019 on-premise**

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Currently i am committing a version number update and then if the build is good , create a tag of Build Number & success

Comment: May you add the code you’ve been using?

Comment: What's the problem now?